# Как подключить стили Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Запускаю сервер на `Socket.io` командой в консоли `node index.js`, 
захожу на свой сервер в браузере, а тут такая картина:
"стили не применились", а файл со стилями перезаписан.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это можно исправить?

**index.js**

```
var http       = require('http');
var fs         = require('fs');
var socketio   = require('socket.io');
var html       = require('escape-html');

var server     = http.createServer();
var io         = socketio(server);
var port       = process.env.PORT || 3004;



fs.readFile('public/index.html', function(err, html_string){

    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    io.on('connection', function (socket){
        socket.on('message', function(data){
            console.log(socket.request.connection.remoteAddress);
            socket.broadcast.emit('message', data);// рассылать всем
            socket.join('some room');
        });
    });

    server.on('request', function(request, response){
        response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});

        response.end(html_string);
    });

    server.listen(port, function(){
        console.log('server running port:' + " " + port);
    });

});
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>socketio</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body style="transition: all 1s">
 <div id="message">
  <p id="gretting">welkome</p>
 </div>
 <div class="panel">
   <form method="post" onsubmit="sendMessage(this.nickname.value, this.message.value); this.message.value = ''; return false">
    <div class="inputs">
     <div class="input-left">
       <input type="text" name="message" placeholder="message" autofocus="off" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div class="input-right">
       <input type="text" name="nickname" placeholder="nickname" autofocus="on" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
     <input type="submit" style="display: none;">
    </div>
   </form>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var messageContainer = document.getElementById('message');

 var socket = io({transports: ['websocket']});

 socket.on('message', function(data){
  console.log(data);
  renderMessage(data)
 });

 function sendMessage(nickname, message){
  var messageUser = {};
  
  messageUser.nickname = nickname;
  messageUser.message = message;
  
  if (nickname && message) {
   socket.emit('message', messageUser);
   renderMessage(messageUser);
  }
  // console.log(messageUser)
 }

 function renderMessage(data){
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  
  div.innerHTML = '<span>' + '<strong>'+ data.nickname +': '+'</strong>' + data.message +'</span>';
  div.setAttribute('style','transition:all .4s;color:#ffff;opacity:0;height:0');
  

  messageContainer.insertBefore(div , messageContainer.firstChild);
  // data.onload = function(){
  //  div.setAttribute('style','transition:all 1s;color:#5cb5e2;opacity:1');
  // }
  setTimeout(function(){
   div.setAttribute('style','transition:all 1s;color:#5cb5e2;opacity:1;height:20px;');
  }, 0);
  // console.log(data.upload);
 }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: а причем тут тег Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут - `server.on('request', function(request, response){` вы должны обработать запрос и вернуть правильный файл. Текущая ваша реализация всегда возвращает одно и то же - это, разумеется, неправильно.

Скорее всего, вы свою реализацию взяли из какого-то примера по socket.io, но не учли что примеры по socket.io показывают вам как обрабатывать сообщения а не как хостить сайт. Хостинг сайта - это базовое знание, предполагается что вы уже умеете это делать до того как начнете работать с socket.io.

---

Запрос от пользователя можно разобрать вручную, в чем поможет [документация](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage). Но проще всего воспользоваться каким-нибудь фреймворком, например [express](https://github.com/expressjs/express) (требует установки через npm):

```
var express = require('express');
var http    = require('http');
var socketio= require('socket.io');

var app     = express();
var server  = http.createServer(app);
var io      = socketio(server);

// ...

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
```

Настроенный таким образом сервер будет пытаться в ответ на любой запрос отдать файл из директории `public` в вашем проекте если там такой файл там есть.

Если нет желания тащить целый фреймворк - можно подключить отдельно пакеты [serve-static](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-static) и [finalhandler](https://github.com/pillarjs/finalhandler).

```
var finalhandler  = require('finalhandler')
var serveStatic   = require('serve-static')
var http          = require('http');
var socketio      = require('socket.io');

var staticHandler = serveStatic(path.join(__dirname, 'public'));
var server = http.createServer(function onRequest (req, res) {
  staticHandler(req, res, finalhandler(req, res))
})
var io            = socketio(server);

// ...
```